# Create a dynamic html in Jquery from session variable

Tags: java, jquery, ajax

I would like to create dynamic html content for seperate http sessions using Jquery. Your kind support is highly appreciated.

```
//This is where I assign my array to a session attribute.
request.getSession().setAttribute("updateTable", game.getTableStatus());
```

I have such function to create 3X3 dynamic table with values passed from array. The way I am using in highlighted line seems wrong. May I have your suggest to fix this problem.

```
function writeTable() {
    // declare html variable (a string holder):
    var html = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        // add opening <tr> tag to the string:
        html += '<tr id="'i'">';
        for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            // add <td> elements to the string:
            html += '<td id="'j'">' + **${sessionScope.updateTable[i][j]}** + '</td>';
            count++;
        }
        // add closing </tr> tag to the string:
        html += '</tr>';
    }
    //append created html to the table body:
    $('#body').append(html);
    // reset the count:
    count = 0;
}
```

Lastly, is that possible to integrate this table with AJAX in order to send back  element id with onClick() event?

I was using below piece of code when it was a static table to fulfill AJAX requirement.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("td").click(function(){ 
        //$(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'gameServlet',
            data: { cellInfo: $(this).attr("id"), rowInfo: $(this).closest("tr").attr("id")},
            success:
              function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                //$(this).text("${sessionScope.mySign}");
              },
              error:
                function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                  $("#result").text(textStatus + ": Error");
                },
            dataType: 'text'
          });
        $(this).text("${sessionScope.mySign}");
    });
});
```

Many thanks!

Comment: What error you are getting. I can see some syntax errors in your code.

Comment: This is what I get when I add ${sessionScope.updateTable[i][j]} to my script : /WEB-INF/views/gamePanel.jsp (line: 95, column: 5) #{...} is not allowed in template text . AJAX part is tested and error free.

Comment: Check my answer below. Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        // add opening <tr> tag to the string:
        html += '<tr id="'+i+'">';
        for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            // add <td> elements to the string:
            html += '<td id="'+j+'">${sessionScope.updateTable['+i+']['+j+']}</td>';
            count++;
        }
        // add closing </tr> tag to the string:
        html += '</tr>';
    }
```

Try this code.

Comment: Thanks for the try Smit but it is still throwing same error.

Answer (score 0):

Still need some advice to iterate my array through JSP:
When I call directly ${applicationScope.tableStatus[0][0]} it returns fine but there is no way to iterate with i and j.

```
function printGame(){   
var html = "";
html+='<table>';
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    // add opening <tr> tag to the string:
    html += '<tr id="'+i+'">';
    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        // add <td> elements to the string:
        html += '<td id="'+j+'">' + '${applicationScope.tableStatus[0][0]}' + '</td>';
        }
    // add closing </tr> tag to the string:
    html += '</tr>';
}
html+='</table>';
return html;
```

}